# On Isomorphisms of tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I have seen different versions of the isomorphism between linear mappings and the tensor product. The one that I'm currently looking at is this: $\operatorname{Hom}_k(V,W)\cong V^* \otimes W$. My questions are these: is this $\operatorname{Hom}_k(V,W)\cong V \otimes W^*$ true as well? And what happens if we make one of the spaces in the hom dual spaces? E.g. is  $\operatorname{Hom}_k(V^*,W)\cong V \otimes W$ true, i.e. can you just add a star on the "hom-side" and remove a star on the other side corresponding to the same space will still maintaining the isomorphism?

Thanks

Clarification: working in finite dimensional vector spaces

Comment: In which category are you working? Are this vector spaces, normed vector spaces, finite, infinite dimensional?

Comment: Vector spaces, finite dimensional

Comment: Are you looking for a particular kind of isomorphism? Because if it's just a regular old linear isomorphism, then all you need to do is count the dimensions of the left- and right-hand sides respectively. Or put another way $V\simeq V^*$, so the duals appearing make no difference to the linear isomorphism class.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I totally forget about that one, now everything makes much more sense. Thanks!

Comment: @WoolierThanThou You can post your comment as an answer if you want, so I can accept the answer

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742627/is-homv-w-simeq-v-otimes-w-naturally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two finite dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic if and only if their dimensions are the same, since all vector spaces are free.

Hence, your question amounts to calculating the dimension of $\operatorname{Hom}_k(V,W)$, which is $\dim(V)\dim(W)$ and that of $V\otimes W^*,$ which is $\dim(V)\dim(W^*)=\dim(V)\dim(W)$.