# Another proof that $Hom(V,W)\cong V^*\otimes W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, tensor-products

This question was already discussed here:
[Why is Hom(V,W) the same thing as V∗⊗W?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161412/natural-transformaton-texthomv-w-and-w-otimes-v)
But, I want to take a different approach in proving that
$$\phi:V^*\otimes W\to \text{Hom}(V,W)$$
is an isomorphism where $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces. Let's fix basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$, $\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$, and $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m\}$ for $W$, $V$, and $V^*$ correspondingly where $\{\alpha_i\}$ is a dual basis for $\{v_i\}$. Next, let's define $\phi$ on basis tensors $\alpha_i\otimes w_j\in V^*\otimes W$ via
$$\phi(\alpha_i\otimes w_j)=f_{\alpha_i}(w_j)$$
where $f_{\alpha_i}(w_j)(v)=\alpha_i(v)w_j$ and extend it linearly since every element $x$ of $V^*\otimes W$ can be written as a finite sum of the basis elements i.e. if $x\in V^*\otimes W$, then $x=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}\alpha_i\otimes w_j$ and
$$\phi(x)=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}\phi(\alpha_i\otimes w_j)=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}f_{\alpha_i}(w_j).$$

Next, I claim that it is enough to show that $\ker(\phi)=0$ since $V^*\otimes W$ and $Hom(V,W)$ have the same dimension and $\phi$ is a linear map (rank-nullity Theorem).

So, let's show that $\ker(\phi)=0$. We can do that by fixing the basis for $V$, $W$, and $V^*$ and showing that if $\phi(x)=0$ then $x=0$ (Details are skipped due to computations).

*Does it make sense?*

*A follow-up question:* Do we have an isomorphism if we take either of these spaces to be infinite dimensional? What would we do in that case?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. No, we don't have the isomorphism in infinite-dimensional case, the reason is that not every linear operator between infinite-dimensional vector spaces has finite rank.

Comment: No, it does *not* make sense: your reasoning has an important gap. You can not just make up a formula on all elementary tensors and extend “by linearity” to all tensors because *elementary tensors span but have lots of linear relations*. You need to observe that your formula on elementary tensors is bilinear in $\alpha$ and $w$ (think of defining a bilinear map on $V^* \times W$ first and then factoring it through the tensor product). For example, you can’t define $f : V^* \otimes W \to V^* \oplus W$ by $f(\alpha \otimes w) = (\alpha,w)$ and then “extend by linearity”, right?

Comment: Only $V$ needs to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! That was helpful. I think I can fix that problem by fixing the basis and defining my map on the basis elements. Can you check that please?

Comment: Also, here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742627/is-homv-w-simeq-v-otimes-w-naturally?rq=1 they defined the map on a tensor $\alpha\otimes w$. I am a little bit confused right now.

Comment: @KCd the OP does say "let's define $\phi$ on basis tensors $\alpha_i\otimes w_j\in V^*\otimes W$ and [...] extend" - the key word being "basis", of course.

Comment: @peterag  Ah, I missed that. I'd say giving a formula on "basis tensors" first is a bad way of constructing a linear map out of a tensor product space, since it is important that its value on *all* elementary tensors is given by the indicated expression in the OP's post. This could be shown as a consequence of the formula on "basis tensors" first, but that's clunky compared to the more elegant technique of constructing a linear map with values specified on *all* elementary tensors initially and then followed by extension to all tensors by the univ. mapping property (unclear of OP knows that).

Comment: @KCd right! I just wanted the OP not to be confused, especially as your comment got 4 "likes"...

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback!